# How do foreigners (international students) work as airline pilots in the USA?

Tags: usa, airline-pilot, cfi

I am planning to study in the USA/Canada (whichever is easier to work afterwards) to get my pilot licenses from 0 to CFII or CFI-MEI, so my best bet is to apply for an F-1 visa program (since it grants 1 year working permit upon completion of my study).

So my question is how can I apply for an airline first officer position after getting 1500 flying hours? What else do I need? (I assume its working permit aside from the one granted by F-1 visa since it's only valid for on-campus jobs and it would be already consumed in getting my 1500 flying hours).

Any correction for the info stated would be much appreciated.

Comment: By the time you have 1500 hours you will probably be at the end of the 1 year working permit period of the F-1 Visa. Will you be applying for an H-1B1 Visa? Or is that your question? Also, I think the F-1 work permit is for work related to your educational curriculum.

Comment: i believe there is an annual flight hours limit of 1000 h for pilot, and a monthly limit of 100, thats not the case, the case now is what are the chances of getting H-1B1 visa, because there is absolutly no chance of getting hired at my home country. and for the F-1 visa its valid for 1 year upon completion of the study and only for on campus jobs and its non-renewable